# How to split a pandas dataframe by each row and include the header for each new dataframe created?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

newbie to Python. 
How can I split the dataframe by each row and create a new dataframe including the header.

My end goal is to use the docx library to put a table of data (created from the dataframe) into word.

An example of how the current datafranme looks:

```
x y z
1 4 5
4 2 4
3 5 5
```

What I would like to create:

```
x y z
1 4 5

x y z
4 2 4
```

Comment: Why is everyone using `iterrows`?

Answer (score 3):

Use List comprehension with iloc

```
l = [df.iloc[[i], :] for i in range(len(df))]

print(l[0])

    x   y   z
0   1   4   5
```

Note: Since we are creating a DataFrame from a single row, df.iloc[i, :] will return a series whereas df.iloc[[i], :] will return a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list comprehension using `DataFrame.iterrows`. Each element in the list will be a one row DataFrame, headers included:

```
frame_list = [pd.DataFrame([x]) for i, x in df.iterrows()]
```

Alternatively a dict comprehension, with the keys being the index from the original DataFrame:

```
frame_dict = {i:pd.DataFrame([x]) for i, x in df.iterrows()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a DataFrame like so:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    _df = pd.DataFrame([row])
    # Add your processing here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and then write data to your docx.

```
   data = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        data.append(df.columns.values)
        data.append(row.tolist())
```

Comment: thanks for this - it brings out the data as a list but I would like to create tables for each set. Is this possible to do?

Comment: It probably is.  Give it a try.